# Rails Heroku migration PG::Error: ERROR: type "location" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

My application seems to work in development, but not when I migrate to Heroku. I generate a Location model:

**20140526153201_create_locations.rb**

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I then add a column to a previously migrated model, Organization, of the type Location.

**20140526162916_add_location_to_organization.rb**

```
class AddLocationToOrganization < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :organizations, :geo_location, :location
  end
end
```

After I push to heroku and run `heroku run rake db:migrate`:

```
Migrating to AddLocationToOrganization: migrating =============
PG::Error: ERROR: type "location" does not exist
LINE 1: ...TER TABLE "organizations" ADD COLUMN "geo_location" location
```

I assume it is because I am trying to use a data type before it exists, but I don't know how to do that. The ordering seems to be logical to me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The 3rd attribute of the `add_column` method is the data type for the database column. So `:location` is not a valid data type for your database. Are you trying to build a belongs_to relationship here or what?

Comment: I may be trying to build a belongs_to relationship. I simply assumed this should work because it worked in development.

Comment: Try re-running the migration in development... it shouldn't have worked. `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20140526162916`. (NOTE: don't do this unless you don't mind losing any data in this column in your development DB of course.)

Comment: Yes, I don't think it should work. I had to do some weird stuff to make it work. I'm going to use belongs_to and see what happens.

Comment: Figured it out. Need belongs_to and has_one.